# Cannot See BottomBar with ListView

Tags: android, listview, navbar, bottombar

I have this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    tools:context="com.tag.instagramdemo.example.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background1">

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/lvRelationShip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </ListView>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:itemIconTint="@color/text"
android:enabled="false"
app:itemTextColor="@color/text"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:clickable="false"
design:menu = "@menu/menu_main"
android:contextClickable="false"/>
```

When I use this layout. I can't see the bottom bar and I can only see the listview. At the top there is the list and nothing else.

Comment: Your parent layout is missing in question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resolve your issue.
I hope it will work for you :)
Please have a look and tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/lvRelationShip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contextClickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        design:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I get an error on <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigaotrBar> for "multile roots"

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have not added a parent layout, do add a parent layout. Enclose the listview inside swiperefreshlayout and enclose the bottombar & swiperefreshlayout inside a parent layout (for eg., relative layout)

   ```
   <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       ....>
       <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
           android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        ...>

            <ListView
               android:id=... >
            </ListView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="64dp"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:background="#ffffff"
       android:enabled="false"
       app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
       app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
       android:clickable="false"
       android:contextClickable="false"
       android:layout_below="@id/swipeContainer"
       app:menu = "@menu/menu_main"/>
   ```
2. Also use

> app:menu

instead of `design:menu` as suggested in 
https://medium.com/@chornenkyy.v/first-look-at-bottomnavigationview-from-android-design-library-8244de85b953

> BottomNavigationView has a method inflateMenu(menu) and if you pass
>   your menu resource file inside it will work. Right after idea with the
>   wrong namespace appear in my mind so I tried to replace ‘design’ with
>   ‘app’ namespace which automatically resolves the attributes. And it
>   actually works. The same story for other three attributes which exist
>   specifically for this view: itemBackground, itemIconTint,
>   itemTextColor.